# Ubuntu puma-manager.conf custom service Job failed to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5, ubuntu-14.04, upstart

I have an Ubuntu 14 server where I run a Ruby on Rails app and I want to create a service that will start the rails server automatically on reboot. This service should allow me to run the Puma server in background, as a daemon process.

Up until a later `apt-get update & apt-get upgrade` I was able to run:

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b unix:/home/appname/site/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock -d
```

The `-d` (daemon) allowed me to run the process in background but now this flag is not available anymore. Puma won't start if I add the: `-d` flag when I start the server.

Following this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/0x263b/683c5d09b1cbf4240884491696eb5e46

I created the following file: `/etc/ini/puma-manager.conf`

```
description "Manages the set of puma processes"

# This starts upon bootup and stops on shutdown
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

pre-start script
    logger -t "puma-manager" "Starting Rails APP"
    cd /home/appname/site/current
    exec bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b unix:/home/appname/site/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock
end script
```

When I run: `service puma-manager start` I receive the following error: `Job failed to start`

I also tried to run with sudo but I receive the same message.

In: `/var/log/upstart/puma-manager.log` I see the error:

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 4: cd: can't cd to /home/appname/site/current
```

Even if I entered a different valid path for cd, I have the same error.